# The Discord app on linux ubuntu desktop does not start

Tags: startup-applications

The Discord app on linux ubuntu desktop does not start and the modal "STARTING..." keeps showing but does not start the app.

PS. I am from Iran and maybe banned to use it whether from the government or the discord itself, but used to open it by a VPN on the starting of the application and worked fine without VPN after the startup (and updates), but now there seems to be no way to start it.

[image]

Here is the content of the syslog when I click on the Discord icon to start using it:

```
Apr 11 13:50:23 asus discord.desktop[53495]: Starting app.                                                                                       
Apr 11 13:50:23 asus discord.desktop[53495]: Starting updater.                                                                                   
Apr 11 13:50:23 asus discord.desktop[53495]: [Modules] Modules initializing                                                                 
Apr 11 13:50:23 asus discord.desktop[53495]: [Modules] Distribution: remote                                                                 
Apr 11 13:50:23 asus discord.desktop[53495]: [Modules] Host updates: enabled                                                                
Apr 11 13:50:23 asus discord.desktop[53495]: [Modules] Module updates: enabled                                                              
Apr 11 13:50:23 asus discord.desktop[53495]: [Modules] Module install path: /home/majid/.config/discord/0.0.14/modules                      
Apr 11 13:50:23 asus discord.desktop[53495]: [Modules] Module installed file path: /home/majid/.config/discord/0.0.14/modules/installed.json
Apr 11 13:50:23 asus discord.desktop[53495]: [Modules] Module download path: /home/majid/.config/discord/0.0.14/modules/pending           
Apr 11 13:50:23 asus discord.desktop[53495]: [Modules] No updates to install                                                              
Apr 11 13:50:23 asus discord.desktop[53495]: [Modules] Checking for host updates.                                                                
Apr 11 13:50:23 asus discord.desktop[53495]: Error downloading with electron net: net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED                               
Apr 11 13:50:23 asus discord.desktop[53495]: Falling back to node net library..                                                                  
Apr 11 13:50:24 asus discord.desktop[53495]: [Modules] Host is up to date.                                                                       
Apr 11 13:50:24 asus discord.desktop[53495]: [Modules] Checking for module updates at https://discord.com/api/modules/stable/versions.json       
Apr 11 13:50:24 asus discord.desktop[53495]: Error downloading with electron net: net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED                               
Apr 11 13:50:24 asus discord.desktop[53495]: Falling back to node net library..                                                                  
Apr 11 13:50:24 asus kernel: [17802.375645] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlp3s0 OUT= MAC=48:5d:60:9e:7f:de:18:0f:76:88:5d:60:08:00 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=224.0.0.1 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=1 ID=58256 DF PROTO=2                                                                                            
Apr 11 13:50:24 asus discord.desktop[53495]: [Modules] No module updates available.                                                    
Apr 11 13:50:24 asus discord.desktop[53495]: [WebContents] did-fail-load -130 ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED retry in 1000 ms             
Apr 11 13:50:27 asus discord.desktop[29263]: [WebContents] retrying load https://discordapp.com/app?_=1618123370762                     
Apr 11 13:50:27 asus discord.desktop[53495]: [WebContents] retrying load https://discordapp.com/app?_=1618132824773                     
Apr 11 13:50:27 asus discord.desktop[29263]: [WebContents] did-fail-load -130 ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED retry in 20000 ms             
Apr 11 13:50:27 asus discord.desktop[53495]: [WebContents] did-fail-load -130 ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED retry in 2627.909209011382 ms 
Apr 11 13:50:32 asus discord.desktop[53495]: [WebContents] retrying load https://discordapp.com/app?_=1618132824773                     
Apr 11 13:50:32 asus discord.desktop[53495]: [WebContents] did-fail-load -130 ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED retry in 4765.554054590117 ms 
Apr 11 13:50:44 asus discord.desktop[53495]: [WebContents] retrying load https://discordapp.com/app?_=1618132824773                     
Apr 11 13:50:44 asus discord.desktop[53495]: [WebContents] did-fail-load -130 ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED retry in 12161.442493055893 ms
Apr 11 13:50:47 asus discord.desktop[29263]: [WebContents] retrying load https://discordapp.com/app?_=1618123370762        
Apr 11 13:50:47 asus discord.desktop[29263]: [WebContents] did-fail-load -130 ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED retry in 20000 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with Ubuntu. According to [this Discord thread](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360056304611-Discord-Accessibility-for-Iranian-Users#:%7E:text=Recently%20Iranian%20users%20were%20not,Discord%20will%20lose%20their%20members), Iran has been blocked from using Discord.

Comment: This thread is 1 year old. Is it still valid? Also, the OP of the Discord question says that the problem has been solved: *"EDIT: The problem is solved now, thanks to whoever upvoted and Discord!"*

Comment: No, I and my coworkers use discord, this just happened yesterday and nothing seems to solve it. We used to use VPN (to have an IP outside Iran) to use discord, but now it does not start I even deleted the `discord` folder on the `.config` folder on my `home` directory but does not start. Three are people now using it on Iran without any problem, I have a problem with it and don't know how to resolve it maybe I should see the sys log.

Comment: The ban appears to have been at the source maybe its back, either way I do not see it as a Ubuntu problem.

Comment: YES IT IS NOT AN UBUNTU PROBLEM, but people in Ubuntu community might help cause it has happened due to some proxy bad config or something like that, please see the syslog on my question which has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, it was due to the proxy setting. I choosed automatic on `Settings->Network->Network Proxy->Automatic`.